# sending mails as a reminder on google app engine using python django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, sendmail, actionmailer

Within one of my apps: say the user has an event to attend to, I want mail to be sent to the user as a reminder, depending upon the time he wants (e.g. 30 mins/15 mins) before the event.

What shall I use to get this functionality?

Comment: Whats' wrong with http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that could work is to create a task to send the reminder, and set the task's countdown or eta, so that it will run at the reminder time (or very close to).
These two settings are mutually exclusive in that you can only set one -- see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html#countdown_arg .

Note that the maximum countdown/ETA for a task cannot be more than 30 days from the current date and time. It might make sense to have a cron that runs regularly and sets up reminder tasks for the next few hours.